# How to use Vuex state when creating custom validation with Vee Validate

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I am trying to do the following:

I would like to pass a token from the Vuex store like this:

```
<template>
  ...
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label for="email" class="label-input">E-mail address</label>
    <input v-validate="validations.user.email" v-model="data.user.email" id="email" class="form-control" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter e-mail" />
    <div v-show="errors.has('email')" id="email-error" class="msg-error text-danger">{{ errors.first('email') }}</div>
  </div>
  ...
</template>

<script>
  ...
  const isUnique = (value) => {
    debugger;
    return axios.post('/api/v1/users/email_validations', { email: value, token: this.$store.state.auth.JWT }).then((response) => {
      // Notice that we return an object containing both a valid property and a data property.
      return {
        valid: response.data.valid,
        data: {
          message: response.data.message
        }
      };
    });
  };

  // The messages getter may also accept a third parameter that includes the data we returned earlier.
  Validator.extend('unique_email', {
    validate: isUnique,
    getMessage: (field, params, data) => {
      return data.message;
    }
  });
  ...

  export default {
    ...
  }
</script>
```

I would like to create a custom validation which sends a request to an API. However, I cannot access the this.$store outside the "export default" section. I got undefined.

Then, I would like to extract this code to a file and import in the components that need it. How could I do that?

I am new with Vue.js and Vee validate, so sorry if it is a simple question.

Thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: You can try importing store before your code inside `<script>` section.
`import store from '@/store/index'` or so then use `store.state` instead of `this.$store.state`, this works in router file at least.

Comment: When I try to import the store. I got this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: store is not defined" when I try to access it. In the script section, this is "Module {__esModule: true, Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Module"}". Does it mean something for you?

Answer (score 1):

Vee-validate does not provide any direct way to access component/instance properties. So you cannot access `this.$store` in your custom validator code. There are multiple alternative ways to achieve this.

Firstly, you can have a hidden read-only input field for the token and use it as a target to validate your unique field. Check the [documentation](https://baianat.github.io/vee-validate/guide/custom-rules.html#cross-field-rules) for more information.

Also, you can try to store the token as [instance property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/adding-instance-properties.html) and later use it in your validator code.

In Vue instance:

```
mounted() {
    Vue.prototype.token = this.$store.state.auth.JWT;
}
```

Then in your validator file:

```
import Vue from "vue";
...
const isUnique = (value) => {
//other code
return axios.post('/api/v1/users/email_validations', { email: value, token: Vue.prototype.token }).then((response) => {
  
  return {
    valid: response.data.valid,
    data: {
      message: response.data.message
    }
  };
});
```